# Motion blur glitching out on random frames

Tags: motion-blur

I am making a scene with a character spinning something around at high speed but for some reason when I use the motion blur located in the render properties [image]

This happens

But it is supposed to stay like
[image]

This seems to happen on a 1 frame interval randomly throughout the animation. is there anyway I could fix it?

Comment: I wonder if there are not some bugs with the Motion Blur, have you tried to tweak the Shutter value or some other values and see what it gives?

Comment: I did try this and it seemed like it was fixing it for one frame and messing up others instead however after finding this I tried using the same new shutter on the frames the issue and there were still more issues.
the picture I've got her only happened the second go around